# Filter by Unique Value then Count by Additional Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique, countif

I've got the following columns in my spreadsheet:

```
URL | Project
-------------
a     1
b     1
c     1
a     2
g     2
x     3
```

I need to count the unique values in my URL column based on project number. For example, if I'm looking at project "1", there are 2 unique URLs (b and c) because "a" has showed up in previous project (project 2).

I've gotten it to work with pivot tables, but the team I support can't seem to wrap their heads around pivot tables so ideally I'd like a formula where they can just change out the project number and get a count.

Comment: At the risk of avoiding your question, is it not possible to train/educate the team on Pivot Tables? Knowing Pivot Tables will be 10000% more beneficial long term.  There are some great simple tutorials out there.

Comment: I agree 100%. That was my initial attempt at a solution however they would just come to me every week asking me to re-teach them or walk them through it again.

Comment: Final comment - perhaps you could show them what *else* they can find, quickly, with a Pivot Table.  The formula will work, sure. But if they change **any** condition, they'd have to come up with a totally new formula, whereas with a pivot table it could be a simple click or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sumproduct seems to give expected results:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$7=E4),--(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,$A$2:$A$7)=1))`

[image]

Comment: @A.Williams - Just pray that your team doesn't ask how that formula works :P